# Tail -f piped to > awk piped to file > file does not work

Tags: linux, bash, awk, tail, output-buffering

Having trouble to wrap my head around piping and potential buffering issue.  I am trying to perform set of operations piped that seem to break at some piping level.  To simplify , I narrowed it down to 3 piping operations that do not work correctly

`tail -f | awk '{print $1}' > file`

results in no data redirected to the file , however

`tail -f | awk '{print $1}'`

results are output to stdout fine

also

`tail -10 | awk '{print $1}' > file`

works fine as well.

thinking it might be buffering issue, tried

`tail -f | unbuffer awk '{print $1}' > file`

what produced no positive results

(note: in original request, i have more operation in between using grep `--line-buffer`, but the problem was narrowed down to 3 piped commands `tail -f | awk > file`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33655

Comment: And regarding `unbuffer`: ["mawk however (the default awk in Debian/Ubuntu and possibly others) buffers output, and also does not seem to work with stdbuf."](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html) I presume the same would apply to unbuffer. Use the techniques in the link above instead.

Comment: If your `awk` supports it, you may try: `awk '{print $1; fflush()}'`.

Comment: @user629299 what are you trying to accomplish really? tail -f is good for monitoring for changes, yet you have > this will clobber the file with a single entry at any given time. Is that what you want?

Comment: @A.Danischewski I'm not sure you really understand the point of `>`. Your mention of _this will clobber the file with a single entry at any given time_ looks a little bit wrong—unless I don't understand what you really mean.

Comment: When you run it one time its fine when you run a subsequent time it will clobber and start again from the watch file.

Comment: @A.Danischewski That might be exactly what the OP wants. How can you assume differently? Besides, this seems to be a toy example to exhibit the problem.

Comment: Exact?? tail -10 then tail -f - thats why I asked him here.

Comment: Thanks  @gniourf_gniourf.  Adding fflush() or system("") did the trick

Comment: Also thanks to @Dark Falcon adding system("") also worked

Answer (score 0):

The following will `tail -f` on a given file and whenever new data is added will automatically execute the while loop:

```
tail -f file_to_watch | while read a; do echo "$a" |awk '{print $1}' >> file;  done
```

or more simply if you really only need to print the first field you could read it directly to your variable like this:

```
tail -f file_to_watch | while read a b; do echo "$a" >> file;  done
```

Comment: @gniourf, your changes would have broken the code although the b to _ would work I'm not sure if it improves the performance and its the same amount of text, the redirect outside to file works except you put a single redirect > not cat >> so it would clobber. I kept the change to highlight the tail -f.

Comment: No, my changes didn't break anything. If you want to leave like this, fine, but putting the redirection at the end of the `while` loop makes the thing more efficient (as you're not opening and closing the file at each iteration). I'm sure what you mean when you say that `>` would clobber. Besides, the `-r` switch to `read` is highly recommended (and should definitely be the default behavior).

Comment: Broken only because I presume that he wanted to cat the way the OP put the question it is possibly okay - I have asked him to be clear. But since its my answer the logic is changed by your edit to clobber from cat thats why I said its broken.

Comment: Then if you really want to append to `file`, put the `>> file` _at the end of the `while` loop_ (after the `done` keyword).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf is right about `-r` and where the `>>` goes and you want to add `IFS=` between `while` and `read` too to avoid leading and trailing white space being stripped from each line.

Comment: @Ed, for what do I want to -r ? According to the man page it turns off backslash as an escape char, and IFS= for what? I don't need to mess with the internal field separator unless I have to.

Comment: His idea of read a _; is good but not really much of a savings as far as I know, the other thing is >> after the while loop to leave the file open - for me on my home system it would be okay and if you are going to expect a lot of activity then I would say its a good idea but if you going to simply leave it running to monitor indefinitely with little amount of data generated its not so good to eat an open file slot. On my system ulimit -Sn and ulimit -Hn = 2048 - seems like a lot but you never know with some applications because they can have swings in the amount of files they open.

Comment: @A.Danischewski you need `-r` so that if the input contains `a\tb` the variable being populated by the read contains `a\tb` instead of `atb`. You need `IFS=` so that if the input starts with white space, e.g. `____a` (`_`=blank), then the variable being populated by the read also starts with that white space instead of being truncated to start with the first non-space character, e.g. `a`. You must ALWAYS write shell read loops as `while IFS= read -r ...` to get the shell to not transform the input unless you have a very specific goal in mind and NEED to remove `IFS=` and/or `-r` to achieve it.

Comment: I think of it as the other way around and this case is not very clear. I suppose for some people there are enough \ backslashed characters to warrant it, shouldn't hurt anything - same for not  stripping leading and trailing spaces it shouldn't hurt usually if thats what you find most useful to presume. If you are tail -f'ing a log file you probably don't care much to see whitespace. There is a reason those settings are default.

Comment: IMHO it's outrageous to presume you can just discard characters from any input source so good luck with that! There is a reason those settings are the default and it's that shell language was created to manipulate files and processes and sequence the calls to tools to do various jobs, not to manipulate text (that's the job awk was created to do) so it's default constructs are not designed for intuitive text processing. If shell was intended to manipulate text you wouldn't have to manually double quote variables when printing them to output the variables literal values and awk wouldn't exist.

Comment: Its not from *any* input source, its a shell so it happens to presume something useful for processing filenames, the `IFS=` is a setting that turns the `IFS` to the null byte `\0` and that is useful for processing filenames since filenames are precluded from containing the null byte character `\0` (the only char I know of that is precluded), thats why utilities like `find` have features like `-print0` so you can process them in shell loops easily but generally speaking its a rarity to see leading or trailing spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to handle log files:

```
tail --follow=name logfile | awk '{print $1 | "tee /var/log/file"}'
```

or for you this may be ok:

```
tail -f | awk '{print $1 | "tee /var/log/file"}'
```

`--follow=name` this prevents stop of command while log file are rolled.
`| "tee /var/log/file"` this is used to get the output to the file.